# SQLite 3 LEFT JOIN where 'IN' is search term

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I've got a database table that needs to be joined to a table that contains countries. The LEFT JOIN is done on country ISO code and is as follows:

```
SELECT table1.city, table2.Country, table2.Flag 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON (table2.ISO = table1.country) 
WHERE table1.id = ?
```

This goes pretty well unfortunately the ISO code for India is 'IN'. This is the country that fails to provide the country data and I think this is because IN is a reserved word for SQL. But how can I preform this query anyway?

Thanks

Ron

Comment: Do you mean that it's failing when you have `WHERE table1.id = 'IN'`?

Comment: No, I meant WHERE table1.ISO = 'IN'. But I overlooked something, problem solved.

Comment: Okay, good to hear it's solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of a reserved word in the *data* should not affect the results at all.  Reserved words are in issue when *compiling* the query, not when running it.

If your query is failing for India, then there is some other problem.

Comment: AAAARGGHHHHH! stupid! It appears there was an enter somewhere in the ISO textfield. I checked for spaces behind the text but not for enters. Lesson learned!